# Associate set mapping against not primary key column

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two objets like:

```
public class Object1 implements Serializable {
    
    protected Integer id; // This is the PK in the xml mapping

    protected Integer otherId; 
    
}

public class Object2 implements Serializable {
    
    protected Integer id; // This is the PK in the xml mapping
    
    protected Set<Object1> object1List; // I want to relate this set against the "otherId" attribute

}
```

And I have this hibernate XML mappings:

```
<class name="Object1" table="Object1Table">
    
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    
    <property name="otherId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="other_id"></column>
    </property>
</class>

<class name="Object2" table="Object2Table">
    
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    
    <set name="object1List" table="Object1Table" lazy="false" fetch="join" >

        <key column="other_id" /> // This is not working

        <one-to-many class="Object1" />
    </set>

</class>
```

But I don't know how to relate the "set" mapping against the "other_id" attribute, it only works against the PK "id" of the "Object1" table.

Does anyone know how to solve this situation?

Comment: Wow. Didn't realize people were still using XML for entity mapping. I believe the `column` attribute refers to the name of the join column. Isn't there a `property-ref` attribute on `one-to-many`, though?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mark the `<set` as `inverse`. Like crizzis mentioned, you'd be better off if you use the annotation model. A lot more people can help you with the annotation model. Apart from that, the HBM XML mapping will be replaced with the JPA orm.xml mapping at some point, so I wouldn't use that approach anymore.